# How to solve this nonlinear partial differential equation stably?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-value

[image]

I'm trying to solve this PDE with a numeric method. For an approximation, a radius $r$ that is sufficiently large (but not infinity) should be enough. When the coefficient of the initial condition $\mathrm {e}^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}$ is $\dfrac{1}{4}$ (i.e., $M(r,0)=\dfrac{1}{4}\mathrm {e}^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}$, the plot of $\left\|M(r,t)\right\|$ as a function of time $t$ and the distance $r$ from the center of the sphere is displayed below:

```
usol=Block[{eps=$MachineEpsilon},
NDSolveValue[{I D[M[r,t],t]==-E^-M[r,t] (D[M[r,t],r,r]-(D[M[r,t],r])^2+(2D[M[r,t],r])/r),
M[r,0]==1/4 E^(-(r^2/2)),Derivative[1, 0][M][eps, t] == 0,M[1000,t]==0},M,{r,eps,4},
{t,0,2},Method->{"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization"->
{"TensorProductGrid","MinPoints"->12000}}]];
G1=Plot3D[4Norm[usol[r,t]],{r,0,3},{t,0,2},AxesLabel->{Style["r ",Italic],Style["t",Italic],
Rotate["\[LeftBracketingBar]M(r, t)\[RightBracketingBar]", \[Pi]/2]}]
```

[image]

When the coefficient of the initial condition is larger, such as $\dfrac{1}{2}$, as indicated by the red line in the plot below, the value of $\left\|M(r,t)\right\|$ increases around that time, causing the graph to be concave at that moment.

```
vsol = Block[{eps=$MachineEpsilon},NDSolveValue[{I D[M[r,t],t]==
-E^-M[r,t] (D[M[r,t],r,r]-(D[M[r,t],r])^2+(2D[M[r,t],r])/r),M[r,0]==1/2 E^(-(r^2/2)),
Derivative[1, 0][M][eps, t] == 0,M[1000,t]==0},M,{r,eps,4},{t,0,2},
Method->{"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization"->{"TensorProductGrid","MinPoints"->21000}}]];
xv=NArgMax[Norm[vsol[0,t]],{t,0.1,0.5}];
G2=Show[Plot3D[2Norm[vsol[r,t]],{r,0,3},{t,0,2},PlotRange->All,
AxesLabel->{Style["r ",Italic],Style["t",Italic],Rotate["\[LeftBracketingBar]M(r, t)\[RightBracketingBar]", \[Pi]/2]},
ViewPoint->{3, -2.2, 4.1}],ParametricPlot3D[{r,xv,2Norm[vsol[r,xv]]},{r,0,3},
PlotStyle->Directive[Red,Thickness->0.005]]]
```

[image]
When the coefficient is greater than 0.8, the equation becomes difficult to solve. Does anyone have any idea to stably solve this equation with a coefficient of 1 or a larger value, even if it is only a numerical method.

Comment: why does your pde system give `NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.` when run without all the options given, as follows. Btw, it is always better to write the pde as separate variable, the BC as separate, and the IC as separate, then use these in the call. There is no need to lump everything in one command making it hard to read  ...

Comment: `eps=$MachineEpsilon;
pde=I*D[M[r,t],t]==-E^-M[r,t] (D[M[r,t],r,r]-(D[M[r,t],r])^2+(2/r D[M[r,t],r]));
ic=M[r,0]==1/4*E^(-(r^2/2));
bc={M[1000,t]==0,Derivative[1,0][M][eps,t]==0};
usol=NDSolveValue[{pde,ic,bc},M,{r,eps,1000},{t,0,2}]`  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXmA6.png)  V 13.1 on windows